# Abnormal Display Glitch On MacBook Pro mid 2015 (Ubuntu)

Tags: display, macbook

This is the video of what is happening:
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskUbuntu/comments/p2gehd/abnormal_display_glitch_ubuntu_macbook_pro/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

I have tried Ubuntu 20.04 and 21.04 (and also PopOS) and the issue persists. Also the weird display happens not only on the desktop but at boot and when shuting it down.

Adding `acpi-osi=` to the boot parameters, installing `xbacklight` doesn't do a thing.

And I am certain the this is not a hardware problem since the macOS works just fine.

Versions tried: 20.04 LTS, 21.04 and PopOS 20.04.

It is present in both live USB as well as after installation.

I have never faced this issue in the past.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: My bad
Here it is:

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskUbuntu/comments/p2gehd/abnormal_display_glitch_ubuntu_macbook_pro/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu did you try?

Comment: Does it also happen when you boot up a live USB?

Comment: Ubuntu version tried: 20.04 LTS, 21.04

Comment: Same results with live usb

Comment: @guiverc Now this question is on topic (reference to that video was quite amusing).